# Green function and Yukawa potential (PDE and integration)

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

The representation of "Yukawa potential" is as follows:

$$G^{\mu} (x) = \int_{0} ^{\infty} (4\pi t)^{-n/2} \exp(-r^2/4t -\mu^2 t )\,dt. $$

I want to show that $ \frac{\log(G^{\mu} (x))}{\mu |x|} \to -1 $ as $ {|x| \to \infty} $.

How can I verify this? Do I need to use the L'Hospital's theorem?

Comment: Silly question: where is used the $x$ in the integral?

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla/ Oh, $r$ means $|x|$ where $x \in \mathbb{R ^n} $